# Fork a phatomjs process

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, fork

I am trying to write a webpage scraper in phantomjs. The task is to recover links/onlick handlers from a given page and click on them. However, once I click on a link, I may be on a different page and then will need to reload the given page again. Is it possible to do this all without reloading the original page, for example, by forking?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not possible from within of PhantomJS. Maybe there is an OS level tool to do this from the outside.

Comment: I will be happy with some OS-level recipe too.